# merging datas and density in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3,3,1000)
t = np.ones(1000)
f = x**2

plt.scatter(x,f) #plot1
plt.scatter(t,f) #plot2

plt.show()
```

I'd like to draw pile datas up.
when you look at upper exmaple, you can see two plot.plot1 is y=x^2 and plot2 is a line of perpendicular with x-axis. datas of plot2 are showing just a line all of datas. it means, i guess there is a section of more dense near the minimum point of plot1 (0,0).

but when you look at plot2 , it just show a line because of no density.

how can i fix this code?

Comment: What do you expect to see on your figure?

Answer (score 0):

Try [axvline](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) if you want a line that is perpendicular to the x-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3,3,1000)
f = x**2

plt.scatter(x,f) #plot1
plt.axvline(1) #plot2

plt.show()
```